# concurrent requests - long running process status progress - chrome issue

Tags: asp.net

I tried to get status progress for long running operation. It works fine in FF:), Opera and IE:?, but in Chrome?! it fails: it never gets into ProcessRequest in Generic Handler. Please, could you suggest what I'm doing wrong?

default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AspNetProgressBar._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Run" OnClick="button_Click" OnClientClick="button_start()"  />
...

<script type="text/javascript">
    function button_start() {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'StatusHandler.ashx',
                data: { statusKeyId: '<%= ViewState["key"] %>' },
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (json) {
                    ... process response
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

...

default.aspx.cs

```
....
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            // TODO: update progress status
        }
        // lblStatus.Text = "Done";
    }
```

StatusHandler.ashx.cs:

```
public class StatusHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        string statusKeyId = context.Request.Params["statusKeyId"];
        if (statusKeyId != null)
        {
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer(GetStatusInfo(statusKeyId ));
                string output = s.Serialize(info);
                context.Response.Write(output);
                return;
        }
        context.Response.Write("{test: \"empty\"}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not: Why doesn't this work in Chrome but why is it working in IE and Firefox.

When clicking on the button, the browser sends a normal http request to the server to replace the entire page. I guess the behaviour wheather javascript is executed or not on the page in that moment is undefined or at least differs between different browsers as you have noticed.

A better approach would be to call your server with an asynchronous request (Ajax) so that the page will remain active in the browser.
Then, when your StatusHandler answers, that your long running process is ready, you can redirect the browser to an url where it can fetch the resulting page from the server.

Comment: Even if I change approach,  still  remains the question "what is so different in chrome?". The timer is running while the page is not replaced with postback request.

Comment: I have tried to explain that in my answer: You leave the current page when clicking the button. So i guess Chrome will not execute any javascript code any more.

Comment: Jan, thanks for your help. It does, the script is running, but old good XmlHttp component doesn't send any request.

Comment: Ok, thats what i meant when talking about "undefined behaviour". The main problem is, that you leave the page by issuing a http request to another url.

Comment: I left the page after 30 sec. Before that, timer has fired 29 events trying to get response from Generic handler, other scripts on page is running fine. Could be about the limited number of concurrent connections in chrome.